# scribe with peersim

Tags: p2p, publish-subscribe

Does anyone can provide any useful information to complete the publish/subscribe protocol "Scribe" using peersim? I already have the paper and the presentation, not very helpful for what I need, I understand the algorithm, but my problem is mainly with peersim.

I have some minor problems with handling the send and receive. I have already built a peer sampling service, over t-man. T-man always gives a list which includes the nodes, that a peer (or better myself, for each cycle) knows.